# Jmeter causing SYN Flood

Tags: tcp, jmeter, handshake, syn

While making HTTP call to server using Jmeter we see SYN flood.
This is causing most probably since Jmeter doesn't sends back the ack as part of 3 way handshake.

Is there any way we can force Jmeter to send the ack back to Server for TCP Connection ?

Answer (score 0):

Given connection succeeded JMeter should normally send ACK, there is no need to "force" it by any means (at least this is true for [JMeter 5.2](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-released-td5728631.html) and [HttpClient4](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html) implementation):

[image]

I would recommend double-checking incoming and outgoing packets using a lower level sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

You can also get extra information regarding what's going on under the hood by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) to [enable debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for the HTTP protocol

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change.